# Executing bundled shell command in a hardened runtime application

Tags: java, code-signing, notarization

I have written a Java application which I want to distribute in form of a macOS application bundle. The application needs to execute a command line application which is also part of the bundle. The bundle is correctly signed (verified using the codesign command) and the hardened runtime is enabled.

I am able to run the application, but then the application fails to execute the bundled command line application.

The code used to execute the command line application:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/path/to/app/bundle/Contents/cli/myCommandLineApplication");
```

The code works fine when I sign the bundle without enabling the hardened runtime.
Once I enable the hardened runtime, I get the following exception:

> Cannot run program "myCommandLineApplication": error=0, posix_spawn failed

What am I doing wrong? Is it even possible to spawn child processes from within a hardened runtime application?

The Java runtime I am using is AdoptOpenJDK (build 11.0.4+11). 
The application is not sandboxed.
The entitlements I used when signing the bundle were

```
<key>com.apple.security.cs.allow-jit</key>
<true/>
<key>com.apple.security.cs.allow-unsigned-executable-memory</key>
<true/>
<key>com.apple.security.cs.disable-executable-page-protection</key>
<true/>
<key>com.apple.security.cs.disable-library-validation</key>
<true/>
<key>com.apple.security.cs.allow-dyld-environment-variables</key>
<true/>
<key>com.apple.security.automation.apple-events</key>
<true/>
```

Comment: I have added the entitlement information in my post. The path to the binary is correct, if I sign the bundle without using the hardened runtime option then the binary can be executed just fine. Only when I add the hardened runtime option then the execution fails.

Answer (score 2):

The issue was related to my build process itself, not the hardened runtime which I suspected. In fact, when I enabled the hardened runtime, also a launcher application was put into place inside the bundle which starts the main application using the bundled JRE.

As this is the AdoptOpenJDK I mentioned, it uses `spawn` for Runtime.exec which caused the issue. Once I added `System.setProperty( "jdk.lang.Process.launchMechanism", "FORK");` to my main method, Runtime.exec was working just fine again afterwards, even  with the hardened runtime enabled.